# Calling an ActiveX control Button from a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a VBA-Excel code which is excecuted by press of a ActiveX control button placed on the worksheet.

I don't want to always press it for it to run and want to control its invocation based on one more macro (separate).

Is it possible and if yes, share insights regarding it.

This is how my worksheet looks like and i want to invoke that button from a separate macro:

[image: This is how my worksheet looks like and i want to invoke that button from a separate macro]

Comment: Why can't you just call the click event directly?

Comment: i want to automate the process

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the macro attached to an ActiveX control you can directly call the sub with the following command:

```
CallByName Worksheets("Sheet1"), "CommandButton21_Click", VbMethod
```

Note, that (by default) Excel will create a `Private Sub` on the worksheet for the button. If you wish to call these subs from a module then you will have to remove the `Private` up-front. Also note, that the sub's name **must** be `NameOfTheButton_Click`.

So, if the above code resides in a sub in a module and you want to make it work then the the code on the sheet could be (for example):

```
Sub CommandButton21_Click()

MsgBox "gotcha"

End Sub
```

If you wish to invoke all macros for all buttons on `Sheet1` then the following code will do:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub tmpSO()

Dim Obj As OLEObject

For Each Obj In Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects
    If TypeName(Obj.Object) = "CommandButton" Then
        CallByName Worksheets("Sheet1"), Obj.Name & "_Click", VbMethod
    End If
Next Obj

End Sub
```

Once again, make sure that none of the subs on `Sheet1` are `Private`. Otherwise, these subs cannot be called from a module but merely from a sub which resides on `Sheet1` as well.